# K Framework: Macros not recursively expanding

Tags: kframework

I was looking at one of the tutorial exercises (the [LOGIK extended](https://github.com/kframework/k/tree/master/k-distribution/tutorial/2_languages/4_logik/extended/exercises/logik-extended) exercise), and for some reason one of the macro rules only expands once. I didn't change anything in `logik.k` other than adding the following lines to the `LOGIK` module so K would actually run the files:

```
syntax KResult ::= Val 
configuration <T> <k> $PGM:Pgm </k> </T>
```

Then I ran:

```
kompile  --backend java  logik.k -d .
krun tests/list-member-1.logik
```

And I got (I added some newlines for readability):

```
<T>
  <k>
    member ( X , [ X , .Terms | _ ] , .Terms ) . 
    member ( X , [ _ , .Terms | T ] , .Terms ) :- member ( X , T , .Terms ) , .Predicates . 
    ?- member ( 5 , [ 1 , .Terms | [ 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 5 , .Terms | [ .Terms ] ] ] , .Terms ) , .Predicates .
  </k>
</T>
```

But I would expect the query to be

```
?- member ( 5 , [ 1 , .Terms | [ 2 , .Terms | [ 3 , .Terms | [4 , .Terms | [5 , .Terms | [6 , .Terms | [5 , .Terms | [ .Terms ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] , .Terms ).
```

To be clear, the following rules seem to be the issue, as I would expect the rules to keep being used until they can't anymore, and I can't see why they would stop now.

```
  rule [T1:Term,T2:Term,Ts:Terms|T':Term] => [T1|[T2,Ts|T']]      [macro]
  rule [T:Term,Ts:Terms] => [T,Ts|[.Terms]]                      [macro]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We switched the meaning of `macro` to mean "non-recursive macro". You need to use `macro-rec` to tell K that this is a macro you want to apply recursively.

This changed happened here: https://github.com/kframework/k/pull/592

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had to completely delete `logik-kompiled/` for the change to take effect---is that expected?

Comment: There is a known issue associated with changing only the attributes of a rule and the parser cache implemented by kompile. In general, if you change a rule's attribute but not the body of the rule, you will have to delete the `kompiled` directory, yes.